# Как правильно вставить вывод echo из базы данных в код css?

Tags: php, css, sql

Как правильно вывести  данные из БД в css код? Нужно изображение в виде  background img, ссылка на которую будет выводится из бд. При попытке залить этот код страница просто не работает, а в  error_log нет записи об ошибке. Подключение к БД верное, как и название столбца

````
border: 1px solid;

width: 1000;
height: 3000;
0em auto;

background-image: ("<?php echo '.$user['my_location'].' ?>;")

padding: 50px;

background-image: url("<?php echo '.$user['my_location'].' ?>;");



overflow: hidden;
position: relative;

}```
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Делайте это через атрибут в html.

Answer (score 0):

Уберите лишние точки

```
<?php echo '.$user['my_location'].' ?>;
```

Думаю, должно быть так:

```
<?php echo $user['my_location'] ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать так

```
<?=$user['my_location']?>
```